# How can I disable the versioning of the JavaScript files?

Tags: wicket

How can I disable the versioning of my JavaScript files? Now I see

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../modal-ver-1455723568000.js"></script>
```

But I want

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../modal.js"></script>
```

Otherwise I have to set breakpoints in Chrome devtools again and again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `YourApplication#init()` add

```
if (usesDevelopmentMode()) { 
  // to disable the timestamps in the names
  getResourceSettings().setResourceCachingStrategy(
    NoopResourceCachingStrategy.INSTANCE);

  // to disable caching in the browser
  getResourceSettings().setDefaultCacheDuration(Duration.NONE);
}
```